# how to understand value of textbox changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input and I change the value of input by a jquery code:

```
$('#areaMin').attr('value',ui.values[0]);
```

and I want to understand when the value changed with this jquery code:

```
$('.filterPanel input').change(function(){
     console.log('tada');
});
```

when I manually fill the textbox and press enter it works but when it fill automaticly it doesn't work.what should I do?

Comment: if you gonna programatically change the value why dont you fire the change event explicitly?

Comment: Are you looking for `keyup`? http://jsfiddle.net/2MvEH/

Answer (score 1):

When the value is changed using script, the change event will not get triggered. You need to do it manually.

```
$('#areaMin').val(ui.values[0]).change();
```

Note: You need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value not [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: should be `$('#areaMin').val(ui.values[0]).trigger('change');` ?

Comment: @rab both are same `.change()` internally calls `.trigger()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#areaMin').val('test');

$('.filterPanel input').keyup(function(){
     console.log('tada');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SetInterval`

```
setInterval(function() { ObserveInputValue($('.filterPanel input').val()); }, 100);
```

`OnChange` it covers all changes

```
$(".filterPanel input").on("change keyup paste click", function(){
    console.log('tada');
})
```

Comment: thank you.onChange doesn't work for me,would you please tell me how to work with setInterval?

Comment: when I use onChange I should click on text box then it works.

Comment: @beautifulmind - No idea what  "ObserveInputValue" is supposed to be - cannot find it documented.  But you can set a reference-variable to the existing value on doc-load, then use interval to keep checking your field for changes; then when it changes, do whatever, and reset your ref-var to what val() returns currently.